# "Drive letters" are inconsistent between reboots

Tags: boot

- XU18.04.2, latest updates.
- m/b: ASUS P8H67-M PRO
- BIOS: latest AMI for this m/b (was upgraded once with official firmware update, no "dirty hacks" or other experiments)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz (no overclocking used, temperatures are OK)

My box have 3 HDDs and one card reader. Some time ago all was OK, but several weeks ago I found that I have no `/dev/sda`: it was shifted to `/dev/sdb` etc... For example, right now I have `sdb`,`sdc` and `sdd`, but don't have `sda`.

On another boot the shift could start from `sdb` (`sdb`-->`sdc`, old `sdc`-->`sdd`) or from `sdc`. Or the shift may not happen at all.

Well, I use "mount by UUID" and "mount by label" in my `fstab`, so this does not cause my box to fail, but it is really irritating. It looks like system can not assign `sda` to first device (boot from real `sda`, root is on real `sdb`), and I don't know where to look for the cause and solutions.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Your hardware (inc. bios/uefi) control how these devices appear to any OS, and the plugging in of a usb-device can change this.  It's not controlled by Ubuntu or any other OS on the machine, but by machine itself in my experience.  Your best place to control is within bios/uefi

Comment: "mount by UUID" and "mount by label" are the proper way to go. Drive letters were never guaranteed to remain the same, since there's no guarantee in which order the drives are discovered by the system at boot or when they're plugged in, so this isn't a bug but expected behavior.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I know about "proper way", and mentioned that. But I never met such behavior before.

Comment: @guiverc no machine-controlled order was changed. That's why I'm so wondering: what happened and why it happened.

Comment: @Troublemaker-DV  I know you know and that's why I've double quoted those :) We're on the same page so far. Such behavior is typical, and those who work in datacenters where swapping hard drives needs to be done frequently  - they see it all the time probably. On desktops/laptop it's not as frequent, but again - it's not guaranteed and depends on what hardware is discovered first, which bus is contacted first. Basically race condition. Now, is there a particular issue that's caused by letter change ? Maybe we can help you figure out a work around

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I understood. But what should I do to make working the utilities which doesn't know about UUID/label, and do access the drives via /dev/sdX? For example, thermal and SMART monitoring tools like `hddtemp`?

Comment: Well, you could use `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` folder. These are symlinks to each device. Symlinks are named after uuid, but point to appropriate `/dev/sda1`. There's also `/dev/disk/by-label`. In fact, now that I think of it, I should be using this more as this seems like more sane way, and the simplest route for your case. We could also get creative with parsing outputs of utilities like `lsblk`, but that's for scripting.  If these suggestions work, let me know - I'll convert this comment to an answer or you can self-document the answer, too :)

Comment: Interesting idea, sure. But it adds another level of abstraction which is not convenient for non-scripting. I got the point and will test it within 12 hours.